# Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token

Tags: ajax, aws-api-gateway

I have a very simple AJAX code that's calling an AWS API gateway endpoint:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://omitted.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/rec',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'zipcode': '1234',
            'url': 'www.google.com'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.info(data);
        }
    });
```

And what I am getting back is:

> Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token 'zipcode': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')`

The data should be in JSON format so What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried:

```
$.post('https://omitted.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/rec',
    {
        'zipcode': '1234',
        'url': 'www.google.com'
    }, 
    function(data, textStatus) {
      //data contains the JSON object
      //textStatus contains the status: success, error, etc
}, "json");

$.post('https://omitted.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test/rec',
    'zipcode=1234&url=www.google.com', 
    function(data, textStatus) {
      //data contains the JSON object
      //textStatus contains the status: success, error, etc
}, "json");
```

And they are returning the same result.

Comment: This is usually a problem that comes from AWS Lambda and how you have the API Gateway setup. Your code looks fine. I would check how you have set the integration on API Gateway.

Comment: @Mark_M it's working fine off postman though Mark, so I suspect the issue shouldn't be in AWS right?

Comment: Yes, that would make me think the endpoint is okay…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That fixed it:

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, callback) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': url,
    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
    'dataType': 'json',
    'success': callback
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the integration request to Proxy integration (in API GW Choose the method, go to integration request window and choose "Use Lambda Proxy integration") and it works!

Answer (score 0):

please remove ' from key like :

```
data: {
        zipcode: '1234',
        url: 'www.google.com'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a problem that comes from AWS Lambda and how you have the API Gateway setup. Your code looks fine. I would check how you have set the integration on API Gateway.

I would check in your integration setup on APIGateway to make sure you have something like:

```
{"body-json" : $input.json('$')}
```

in your template mapping to deal with the JSON.

Comment: We're on the AWS console right now, where can we find or add that in?

Comment: This is in the Method Integration tabs in API Gateway. If you click on the POST under the resource it opens up. It's in 'Body Mapping Templates' under 'Integration Request'. It's a little annoying to setup. A lot of people use the Lambda Proxy integration to avoid dealing with this.

Comment: Alright we went in & added a new content-type `application/json` then we went into the template, where do we add in that line?

Comment: If you added a content-type, you should be able to click on it. It will open an empty text area underneath. You'll want something like above (I edited it to include the braces).

Comment: Ok now we have 2 different errors one from postman:
`{"stackTrace": [["/var/task/lambda_function.py", 41, "lambda_handler", "if event['zipcode'] in postcode_dict:"]], "errorType": "KeyError", "errorMessage": "'zipcode'"}`

And another one from the ajax request:

`{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token \'zipcode\': was expecting (\'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@5e1e9e24; line: 1, column: 9]"}`

Comment: Hmm, sorry for that. The JSON in the lambda will be attached to the 'body-json' But it doesn't sound like it's fixed the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your client code is perfectly fine, the issue is with the endpoint implementation, server is not able to parse the json.